# Struts2 Validation - No Validation on Input

Tags: struts2, validation

Every tutorial I have found on Struts2 Declarative validation explains how to make the fields validated which is nice and easy. But how do you enter the page with out it being validated?

I have the below Action mapped

```
    <package name="admin" namespace="/admin" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="display_*" class="action.admin.AdminAction" method="display">
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/secure/admin/adminUsers.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/secure/admin/adminUsers.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Shouldn't I be able to call it with admin/display_input.action to skip validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `defaultStack` (it's activated by default), see http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/interceptors.html (`<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>`)

It contains `validation` interceptor which will ignore validation only on methods `input,back,cancel,browse`. So you can action via one of these methods, or you can use interceptor stack without `validation` interceptor (`basicStack`, for example).

You also can annotate your action method with `@SkipValidation` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg69320.html

Try setting the method attribute to method="{1}".